# Encouraging the Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, html, browser, geolocation

When one uses the [W3C Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) and calls the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function the browser prompts the user to accept or decline the sharing of their location.

It is my understanding that the request for permission cannot be handled by Javascript & The DOM; and rightly so! You'd have malicious developers asking questions like *Do you like Beer?*, user clicks *Yes*, and developer steals their location silently.

The notification to share your location though, can come off quite passively; Some users might even think *oh, that's just my browser blocking a popup* without giving the notification much thought.

I'm wondering if anybody has developed a plugin that identifies the users' browser and *draws* an arrow, or somehow highlights the fact that the browser is asking for their location *inside the document*. Something that accentuates the accept button... resolution and platform independent?

Comment: Since it's generally discouraged to code browser specific code, I'd discourage such things. Especially since it's all rather new and a particular browser implementation may still change. What about a general *"Your browser will ask you to allow geolocation now!"* notice? Overall interesting question though, +1.

Answer (score -1):

If you receive a "PERMISSION_DENIED (numeric value 1)" just inform the user with a popup.

Comment: I know how to detect if they clicked Deny. That's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to actually bring focus to the Accept button itself.

Comment: search for "PERMISSION_DENIED" on this page: [Using_geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation)

Comment: That is outside of the browsers scope.